# 2 dimensional C array as Objective C parameter, malloc incompatible with sizeof operand

Tags: objective-c, c

I need to create a pointer to a 2 dimensional C array which will be passed as a parameter to a function later. This is what I am attempting:

```
int64_t (*results)[numSamples] = malloc(sizeof(int64_t[numSamples])*amountPossible);
```

The result I was hoping for is a pointer to a 2 dimensional array that would effectively be something like `int64_t[amountPossible][numSamples]`, but using Analyze in Xcode I get the warning

> Result of 'malloc' is converted to a pointer of type
>   'int64_t[numSamples]', which is incompatible with sizeof operand type
>   'int64_t[numSamples]'

numSamples will always be the same value, but amountPossible is variable. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in the analyzer. The only permutation I discovered which doesn't trip the analyzer is to break up the statement:

```
size_t bytes = sizeof(int64_t[numSamples]) * amountPossible;
int64_t (*results)[numSamples] = malloc(bytes);
```

Which shouldn't of course be required!

Report it as a bug to Apple.